# get_posts() return NULL using a custom plugin and add_submenu_page() with Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, errors, get-posts

Inside a custom plugin and using `add_submenu_page()` for custom post type I want to display one post.
As the other post_type I use `get_posts($the_id, $arr_params)` to get information about it, except in this case where it return `NULL`.
The corresponding ID exist in database .

the creation of this add_submenu_page() :

```
add_submenu_page( null , 'Modify Organization', 'Modify Organization','manage_options', 'edit-org','atv_edit_org');
```

The url of this custom post page is:

```
https://website.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=org_post_type&page=edit-org&id=1998
```

So, using `get_posts()`:

**Update = `get_post()` not `get_posts()`.**

```
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['page'] == 'edit-org'):
//include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');

$post_id = $_GET['id'];
$args_org_post = array('post_type' => 'org_post_type', 'post_status' => 'draft');
$data_post = get_post($post_id, $args_org_post);
var_dump($data_post);
```

it return `NULL

Comment: You’re using get_post incorrectly. It doesn’t accept an array or arguments. get_posts does, but it doesn’t accept an ID. You seem to have confused the two.

Comment: Thanks, In my research I confused get_post() and get_posts() parameters.